# Unexpected if statement behaviour

Tags: bash, shell

I was running a small bash script, but I couldn't figure out why it was entering a if block even when condition should be false.

```sh
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$@"="-h" || "$@"="--help" ]]
then
    echo 'Show help'
    exit
fi

echo 'Do stuff'
$ ./script.sh 
Show help
$ bash -x script.sh 
+ [[ -n =-h ]]
+ echo 'Show help'
Show help
+ exit
$ bash -x script.sh -option
+ [[ -n -option=-h ]]
+ echo 'Show help'
Show help
+ exit
```

So why is `$@` equal to `-n` when I didn't pass any arguments? Also even if it is, how does `-n =-h` evaluate to true? When I do pass an argument `-option`, why is it evaluated to true, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whitespace is significant. Spaces between the arguments to `[[` are mandatory.

```
if [[ "$@" = "-h" || "$@" = "--help" ]]
```

Also, `"$@"` means "all of the command-line arguments". It would be better to just check a single argument.

```
if [[ "$1" = "-h" || "$1" = "--help" ]]
```

And for what it's worth, variable expansions in `[[` don't have to be quoted. It doesn't hurt, and quoting your variables actually a good habit to develop, but if you want you can remove the quotes.

```
if [[ $1 = -h || $1 = --help ]]
```

Comment: Leaving off quotes in `[[ ]]` is only safe on the left side of the `=` -- on the right side, leaving them off allows pattern matching instead of literal string equality. Just double-quote all variable references, it's much easier than trying to keep track of all the weird cases where something unexpected can happen if you leave the quotes off.

Answer (score 1):

`[[ string ]]` return true if string is not empty, i.e. it's a shorcut for

```
[[ -n string ]]
```

In your case, the string was `=-h`, that's why you see

```
[[ -n =-h ]]
```

To test for string equiality, you have to use the `=` (or `==`) operator, that must be preceded and followed by whitespace.

```
[[ "$@" = "-h" ]]
```

Note that `"$@"` means all the arguments:

```
set -- a b c
set -x
[[ "$@" == 'a b c' ]] && echo true
```

gives

```
+ [[ a b c == \a\ \b\ \c ]]
+ echo true
true
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have already explained the problems with your code. This one shows that

- bashisms such as `[[ ... ]]` are not needed,
- you can gain flexibility by using a `for` loop to check whether *at least one* of the command-line argument matches `-h` or `--help`.

## Script

```sh
#!/bin/sh

show_help=0
for arg in "$@"; do
  shift
  case "$arg" in
    "--help")
      show_help=1
      ;;
    "-h")
      show_help=1
      ;;
    *)
      ;;
  esac
done

if [ $show_help -eq 1 ]; then
  printf "Show help\n"
  exit
fi
```

## Tests

After making the script (called "foo") executable, by running

```sh
chmod u+x foo
```

I get the following results

```sh
$ ./foo
$ ./foo -h
Show help
$ ./foo --help
Show help
$ ./foo bar
$ ./foo bar --help
Show help
$ ./foo bar --help baz -h
Show help
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. Perfect way to parse options. What is `esac` for?

Comment: `esac` closes the switch statement (it's "case" written backwards).